# Express gateway liveness or readyness

Tags: express-gateway

I am setting the cloud environment for my application. We are using express gateway as entry point. How to check liveness or readiness of the express gateway on linux environment? Please let me know is there any configuration or url to check the health of api gateway?

Answer (score 0):

we do not have explicit liveness and readiness endpoints. However, most of the users, me included, have been using with success the `/users` endpoint from the Admin API.

Would that solve your use case? Otherwise you could easily plug any express-based middleware accomplishing such thing and get away with it.

Comment: Can we hit "/users" api from network? These api are working with localhost but when i am trying to access those with the IP from another machine they are not working.

Comment: Can you please name those express-based middleware ?